# Invalid unicode character causing MySQL string error

Tags: mysql, unicode, chinese-locale

I need to add a record to our MySQL database (via Omeka) that includes an invalid unicode character ([this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2aa27/index.htm))

The error message I get via Omeka is:

```
Mysqli statement execute error : Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xAA\xA8\xA7\xE7\x94...' for column 'text' at row 1
```

The database field is longtext with collation utf8_unicode_ci. There are already a lot of records in this table and I'm not quite sure what I should change without affecting the other data already in it. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused how a character can be defined, yet invalid…

Comment: are you using prepared statements  to insert this value rather than some string concatenation? Some chinese characters will require utf8mb4. The utf8 is only the 3 character version.

Comment: I'm using Omeka; it's a standard webapp in php that inserts the values.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO utf8mb4;

Meanwhile, the text for that row in that column is probably truncated or the whole row is missing.

As best as I can tell, F0AAA8A7 is not yet assigned, but I think it is in the area of Chinese characters, not Emoji, which also need utf8mb4. It is Unicode "codepoint" 2AA27.

Comment: Yes, it's this Chinese character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2aa27/index.htm. I make most MySQL changes via phpMyAdmin these days, so I can change to utf8mb4 that way (utf8mb4_unicode_ci). I'll try it out after making a backup.

Comment: @Another_Omeka_User - Aha.  Firefox can render that; Chrome cannot.  fileformat.info uses an image; scarfboy.com (http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%F0%AA%A8%A7) expects the font to take care of rendering.